# waiting for all devices to come online -> Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Every day when I start up my Android Studio and start running the emulator, it builds, then goes on saying:

> waiting for all devices to come online

and then gives this error:

> Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

I reinstall my Emulator and then it works until the end of the day. The next day the same.

Did anyone else have this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Try to wipe the data of the emulating device.

Comment: @Ruthvik I have tried that but it doesn't help.

Comment: When i encountered a similar situation, i wiped out the data and then it worked normally. If you are running the emulator for the first time then it might take 5 to 10 minutes depending on your computer speed (or even faster). I suggest you to be patient for atleast 10 minutes. Even after that the device is not online then there might be some other issue...

Answer (score 2):

Solved the issue by ticking "Use libusb backend"

Just in case this helps anyone

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T77l.png

Comment: This no longer seems to be an option - Windows 10, Android Studio 20202.3.1. The rest of the panel is the same, except the Use libusb checkbox and ADB server radio buttons are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring up the Emulator from AVD manager then when device is up click the play button.

Also update the Studio there could be some problem with your version.

Comment: I have reinstalled my Android Studio, but it didn't solve this problem. If I bring the emulator up from the AVD manager and then run the project, it gives the error that there is already an Emulator started.

Answer (score 0):

The error of already started emulator can be solved by deleting the file with .LOCK extension in the path C:\Users[your username].android\avd[your virtual device name.avd]\
Before deleting the lock file you need to close android studio since the lock files is being used by android studio.

The time out error is solved in my case by wiping the data. But this option should be used in case of using virtual devices only.